# Representing unmanaged memory

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management

I have a simple class that wraps around some unmanaged memory, like this:

```cs
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    private unsafe T* _ptr;
    private int _length;

    public int Length => _length;

    public unsafe Wrapper(int length)
    {
        _ptr = ...; // Assigns ptr to some pointer from unmanaged code
        _length = length;
    }
}
```

Now I would like to have a way to be able to use `_ptr` safely and universally with many of `.NET 5`'s functions, so the solution to me would be to use `Span<T>`. However, a `Span` is allocated on the stack so I cannot cache the span.

Here is what that would look like:

```cs
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    private unsafe T* _ptr;
    private int _length;

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get => _ptr[index]; // Works, but not very safe. Bounds checking reduces performance by 2x
        set => _ptr[index] = value;
    }

    // I could do this, but every time this is accessed I have to create a new span. (Like in the indexer)
    public Span<T> Span => new Span<T>(_ptr, _length); 
    public int Length => _length;

    public unsafe Wrapper(int length)
    {
        _ptr = ...; // Assigns ptr to some pointer from unmanaged code
        _length = length;
    }
}
```

This would work well except for the fact that I also want to implement an indexer, which might be called millions of times, and that means I would have to create a `Span<T>` millions of times, which is not ideal for a single access.

The compiler would optimize most of it out, but as I expected, not everything could be optimized out as shown by a simple benchmark.

I could also use the raw `_ptr` for the indexer, but that could lead to some security issues if the caller goes out of bounds. I also simply implemented my own bounds checking, but the performance was **2x** worse!

EDIT: **I did a benchmark comparing iterating through `Wrapper` billions of times, one using a `Span` and the other indexing through a raw array, and the array performed consistently better.**

Comment: `Span` is a struct, not a class. So no allocation.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman  Yes, but if its still not optimal creating millions of spans just for calling the indexer a bunch of times

Comment: A span only has two fields. In a release build, it's likely the property getter will be inlined & the struct decomposed, allowing even further optimisations. Span is intended for speed and safety.

Comment: @Win32ApiUSer Why on earth do you think using an indexer would mean creating "millions" of spans? Are you aware of how value-types work in the CLR?

Comment: I did a test comparing accessing a `Span<byte>` vs `byte[]` in this class's indexer and accessing the `byte[]` via the indexer had a clear and repeatable performance advantage

Comment: Which runtime are you testing and how? (https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/archive/docs/specs/span.md#designrepresentation / https://adamsitnik.com/Span/#span-vs-array)

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I think you misunderstood what I meant. My benchmarked compared having an indexer which returned (referencing the above code), Span[index], where Span created a new span based on the ptr, and just accessing this: arr[index]. I'm using .NET 5 btw